# Can I simplify this C# 7 switch statement to not re-state the type?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I'm looking at C# 7's new switch statement, and while it's awesome that I can switch on the type as part of pattern matching, I wonder if I can avoid re-stating the type in case I already know it?

Example:

```
private static void BetterSwitchCase(string s)
{
    switch (s)
    {
        case string x when x.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(x, out int i):
            Console.WriteLine($"s is a string that parses to {i}");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("No Match.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Here, my case statement re-states `string x` even though the type I'm switching on is already a string, and I only care about it's `Length` and if it `int.TryParse`s.

Just omitting it doesn't compile:

```
//  Syntax error, ':' expected
case when s.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(s, out int i):

// A constant value is expected
case s when s.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(s, out int i):
```

So I'm just wondering if there is a way to omit it, or if it's just part of the pattern matching syntax that I have to accept.

Comment: I don't think this is a good use-case for pattern-matching - a simple `if` or ternary expression will do.

Comment: @Dai In this case, absolutely. I'm more thinking if there are multiple conditions (e.g., if you have to switch on a bunch of error messages (possibly even localized ones) because of poorly designed APIs). Right now, an if-cascade or a Dictionary of Predicates work, but the new switch syntax is another potential tool to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't omit the type (or `var` keyword masking the type), as it is a part of pattern matching here.

Consider class hierarchy (this will not compile in `C#7`, but will compile in further versions after full implementation)

```
class Geometry();
class Triangle(int Width, int Height, int Base) : Geometry;
class Rectangle(int Width, int Height)          : Geometry;
class Square(int width)                         : Geometry;
```

Now we get a variable like this:

```
Geometry g = new Square(5);
```

Now we do the `switch` over it:

```
using static System.Console;

switch (g)
{
    // check that g is a Triangle and deconstruct it into local variables
    case Triangle(int Width, int Height, int Base):
        WriteLine($"{Width} {Height} {Base}");
        break;

    // same for Rectangle
    case Rectangle(int Width, int Height):
        WriteLine($"{Width} {Height}");
        break;

    // same for Square
    case Square(int Width):
        WriteLine($"{Width}");
        break;

    // no luck
    default:
        WriteLine("<other>");
        break;
}
```

Back to your case, consider the code:

```
switch (s)
{
    case string x when x.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(x, out int i):
        Console.WriteLine($"s is a string that parses to {i}");
        break;
    // will not compile with error
    // An expression of type string cannot be handled by a pattern of type int.
    case int x:
        break;

    // will win pattern matching and print the line
    // {s} is an object
    case object x:
        Console.WriteLine($"{s} is an object");

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("No Match.");
        break;
}
```

So **type checking is a part of pattern matching** and you can't omit it (and for `C#7` it's only available to switch on types, full support is planned for `C#8`). Example was brought from [here](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/01/20/new-features-in-c-sharp-7/). The previous step was the `when` clause for [exception handling in `C#6`](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/pattern-matching.aspx)

Comment: I think you should make it more clear that the record syntax and the type deconstruction syntax are not in C# 7.

Comment: Personally, I don't see how this answers the question, I think the OP already knows how pattern matching with types works, and is specifically looking to simplify the code, which is why I didn't upvote this answer (but I didn't downvote it either).

Comment: At the end of the question OP asks, can he omit the type. I explain that no, he can't

Comment: FWIW, I think this shows why making the type info option would be an issue in terms of Syntax. The answer to "Can I omit the type info?" is "No". @svick gave a good workaround though,

Answer (score 8):

You could use `var` pattern:

```
case var x when x.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(x, out int i):
```

Or even better, `var` pattern with a discard:

```
case var _ when s.Length == 3 && int.TryParse(s, out int i):
```

Comment: In the same vein, `out int i` can be `out var i` since `int.TryParse()` already implies that it will return an `int`.

Comment: The VS syntax highlighting is a bit confused by the discard method, it highlights `_` as if it was a keyword.

Comment: @Stijn [That's going to be fixed in VS 15.5.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/20561)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following. Aesthetically it is displeasing, but it does have two advantages. It's fairly easy to understand and it compiles. The x ends up not being used. The variable in the switch statement can be a dummy. If you have  particularly complicated heavily nested if-then code this method can be used and can be easier to /read/understand. Anyone know a better way?

```
switch (dummyString)
{
    case string x1 when word = "entry": 
        DoEntry(); 
        break;

    case string x2 when word = "exit" && door="front":
        DoFrontDoorExit();
        break;

    case string x3 when word = "exit" && door="rear":
        DoRearDoorExit();
        break;

    case string x4 when Tomorrow() == "Tuesday":
        BuyALotteryTicket()
        break;

    default: 
        break; 
}
```